# Check validations dynamically in Controller [ASP.Net MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model, controller, modelstate

I'm developing an MVC application for Travels portal. Here, I have a form to submit a new Travel request and my controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(CreateOrEditCabBookingDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CabBookingAppService.Instance.CreateOrUpdate(model);
    }
    return PartialView("_CreateOrUpdateCabBooking", model);
}
```

I have not included any validation annotations to my **Model** because I want them to execute dynamically based on some conditions. Is it possible to have validations dynamically in controller and add them to **Model State**?

Example: Based on **StatusId** property value, set **StartDate** as Required.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(CreateOrEditCabBookingDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        If(model.StatusId == 10)
        {
           // Check validation here
           // Property "StartDate" is Required
        }

        CabBookingAppService.Instance.CreateOrUpdate(model);
    }
    return PartialView("_CreateOrUpdateCabBooking", model);
}
```

Based on the inputs, I changed like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(CreateOrEditCabBookingDto model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FromDateTime))
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("FromDateTime","Date is Required");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CabBookingAppService.Instance.CreateOrUpdate(model);
    }
    return PartialView("_CreateOrUpdateCabBooking", model);
}
```

And My View Looks like this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOrEdit", "Travel", null, new AjaxOptions
 {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
     OnBegin = "OnBegin",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     UpdateTargetId = "PopupId"
 }, new { id = "frm" }))
 {
    ............................
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDateTime)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDateTime, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", autocomplete = "off" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromDateTime)
     </div>
     ............................
 }
```

Comment: You can use conditional validation attributes, for example from the [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) plugin

Comment: Once you have done a custom validation on any property in your action method, you can call ModelState.AddModelError("FieldName","Error message") to add any custom property errors . Now you can check ModelState.IsValid property after this and return the appropriate view.

Comment: @Nish26 can I get any references for this?

Comment: You can check [Custom Validation Section on this blog](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/) or look at [ModelStateDictionary documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.1) ..ModelState is object of ModelStateDictionary..I linked here for asp.netcore ..I believe it is similar in asp.net mvc as well.

Comment: @Nish26 I did the same, But error is not showing

Comment: Please share code for your view and updated change in your action method..

Comment: @Nish26 I have updated the Question based on your inputs